# Representation theory of the full linear monoid

Tags: rt.representation-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

The **full linear monoid** $M_N(k)$ of a field $k$ is the set of $N \times N$ matrices with entries in $k$, made into a monoid with matrix multiplication.
A **representation** of $M_N(k)$ on a vector space $V$ over $k$ is a monoid homomorphism

$$   \rho \colon M_N(k) \to \textrm{End}(V). $$

What is the classification of representations of the full linear monoid?

(Note: this is different than asking about representations of $M_N(k)$ viewed as an *algebra.*)

We get a bunch of irreducible representations of $M_N(k)$ from Young diagrams with $\le N$ rows.  The vector space

$$ (k^N)^{\otimes n}= \underbrace{k^N\otimes \cdots\otimes k^N}_{\mbox{$n$ copies}} $$

is a representation of $M_N(k)$ in an obvious way.   Given a Young diagram with $n$ boxes and $\le N$ rows, we get a minimal central idempotent in $S_n$, and we can use this to project $(k^N)^{\otimes n}$ down to a subspace that is a representation of $M_N(k)$.

I believe these are all the **polynomial** irreducible representations $\rho$ of $M_N(k)$: that is, those where the matrix entries of $\rho(T)$ are polynomials in the matrix entries of $T \in M_N(k)$.

1. Is this correct?

We get more irreducible representations using the absolute Galois group of $k$.  Any field automorphism of $k$ gives an automorphism $\alpha$ of the monoid $M_n(k)$, and composing this with a polynomial irreducible representation $\rho \colon M_n(k) \to \mathrm{End}(V)$ we get a new representation $\rho \circ \alpha$ which is still irreducible, but not polynomial unless $\alpha$ is the identity.

But when $N = 1$, at least, there are even more irreducible representations of the full linear monoid!  Then $M_1(k)$ is the multiplicative monoid of $k$, and it has a 1-dimensional irreducible representation sending $x \in k$ to multiplication by $x^n$ for any $n \ge 0$.

The point here is that the multiplicative monoid of $k$ has endomorphisms that don't come from field automorphisms.  There can also be others that combine raising to a power with field automorphisms: e.g. $M_1(\mathbb{C})$ has a 1-dimensional irreducible representation sending $z \in \mathbb{C}$ to multiplication by $z^4 \overline{z}^3$.

Since endomorphisms of the multiplicative monoid of $k$ not arising from field automorphisms don't preserve addition, I don't see how to use them to get extra representations of $M_N(k)$ for $N > 1$.

So:

2. Are all the irreducible representations of $M_N(k)$ for $N > 1$ of the form $\rho \circ \alpha$ where $\rho$ comes from a Young diagram with at most $N$ rows and $\alpha$ comes from a field automorphism of $k$, or are there more?
3. Do all the irreducible representations of $M_N(k)$ for $N = 1$ come from endomorphisms of the multiplicative monoid of $k$?
4. Are all finite-dimensional representations of $M_n(k)$ completely reducible?

Comment: I'll write more later.  The polynomial representations are the representations as an algebraic monoid not just as a monoid and probably requires algebraically closed

Comment: For k finite the algebra of M_(k) in characteristic of k is not semisimple so not all representations are completely reducible

Comment: You should look at the with of Putcha, Renner and Doty in representations as algebraic monoid

Comment: If k is finite and you look at representations  over fields of characteristic different than that of k, then M_(k) has a Frobenius algebra and is isomorphic to a direct product of matrix algebras over group algebras in GLr with 0\leq r\leq n.  This is work of Putcha, Okninski and Kovacs

Comment: My book talks about the finite field case.  Even over k the irreps of M_n(k) are parameterized by irreps of GLr(k) for r\leq n

Comment: Actually it seems to me the argument for the finite case works in general to show the irreps of M_n(k) over k are parameterized by the irreps of GL_r(k) for 0\leq r\leq n. It has descending chain on principal left and right ideals and finitely many two-sided monoid ideals

Comment: You might look at Okninski's book on matrix semigroups too.   In any event your problem reduces to general library groups for classification of irreps

Comment: I saw the title of the question, and thought “perfect question for @BenjaminSteinberg, I should ping him”. Then I saw you already made 7 comments and an answer….! :-)

Comment: I remember ( from a long time ago) that  Leonid Krop did some work which might be relevant.

Answer (score 10):

At least over an algebraically field, the polynomial representations are precisely the representations of $M_n(k)$ as an algebraic monoid and I don’t see immediately why that would change over a nonalgebraically closed field, but I am not an expert.

To classify irreducible representations of $M_n(k)$ over any field $F$ is the same as to classify irreducible representations of $GL_r(k)$ for $0\leq r\leq n$ over $F$ (where $GL_0(k)$ is the trivial group).

This follows from old results of Munn and Ponizovskii on representations of finite monoids that were eventually extended to monoids satisfying certain finiteness conditions that $M_n(k)$ satisfies.  I don’t know the classification for $GL_r(k)$ but somebody else might.

The argument is like this.  A principal ideal in a monoid $M$ is a set of the form $MaM$.  The principal ideals of $M_n(k)$ are well known to be of the form $I_r$ where $I_r$ consists of all matrices of rank at most $r$ (with $0\leq r\leq n$.  Let $e_r$ be the diagonal row echelon form rank $r$ idempotent.  Note every rank $r$ idempotent is conjugate to $e_r$.  Note that $e_rM_n(k)e_r\cong M_r(k)$ and so we can identify its group of units $G_r$ with $GL_r(k)$

Let $V$ be an irreducible $M_n(k)$ module over a field $F$.  Then there is a least $r$ with $I_rV\neq 0$.  Then one easily checks that $e_rV$ is an irreducible representation of $e_rM_n(k)e_r\cong M_r(k)$ that is annihilated all elements not belonging to $G_r\cong GL_r(k)$ and so is an irreducible representation of $G_r$.

Conversely, given an irreducible representation $W$ of $Gl_r(k)$ (identified with $G_r$), there is a unique irreducible representation $V$ of $M_n(k)$ with $I_{r-1`}W=0$ and $e_rV\cong W$ as representations of $G_r$.  You can construct $V$ as $(FM_n(k)/FI_{r_1}\otimes_{FG_r}W)/N$ where $N$ is largest submodule annihilated by $e_r$.  This kind of argument is a mixture of Munn-Ponizovksii’s argument for finite semigroups and Green’s condensation technique which coincidentally appears in his book on polynomial representations (he also introduced the study of principal ideals in structural semigroup theory).

The details of how this works can be found in my book on representation theory of finite monoids.  Finiteness can be replaced with taking a monoid $M$ with a finite unrefinable chain of two-sided ideals such that $eMe$is Dededkind finite for all idempotents $e$.  I think this kind of result is in the generality you need in Okninski’s book Semigroups of Matrices.

As to complete reducibility, this I do not know much about for the infinite case.  For $k$ finite and $F$ any field it was first shown by Putcha and Okninski that $FM_n(k)$ is semisimple whenever $F$ is of characteristic $0$.  They showed that this is true for any finite monoid of Lie type (the finite analogues of reductive algebraic monoids).  Kovacs then showed $FM_n(k)$ is Frobenius if and only if the characteristic of $k$ is not the same as that of $F$. You can find his proof in my book.  In fact, Kovacs showed if $R$ is any commutative ring in which the characteristic of $k$ is invertible, then $RM_n(k)$ is isomorphic to a direct product of $M_{n_r}(RGL_r(k))$ with $0\leq r\leq n$ where $n_r$ is the number of $r$-dimensional sub spaces of $k^n$.  In particular, every representation of $M_n(k)$ over $F$ is completely reducible iff the characteristic of $F$ does not divide the order of $GL_n(k)$.  I have a recent paper giving explicitly the Frobenius form for $M_n(k)$ in good characteristic, which is easier than Kovacs’s proof since you can check by hand the form is Frobenius.  The direct product decomposition follows from $M_n(k)$ being von Neumann regular and having a Frobenius algebra by a result you can find in my book

The algebra $kM_n(k)$ is not self-injective if $k$ is finite.

I’d like to hope if $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then each finite dimensional representation of $M_n(k)$ is completely reducible but I don’t know.  Let me add Putcha and Okninski showed if $k$ is any field and $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then $FM_n(k)$ has trivial Jacobson radical.

Comment: Are quiver and relations known of $kM_n(k)$ for some special cases, when it is not semismple (possibly over a splitting field) ?

Comment: I don't think much is known in this case when k is finite.  At the minimum you need to know the quiver of the general linear group.  You will have the disjoint union of the quivers if general linear groups plus some other edges

Comment: Ok, I might try a bit for $n=2$. Is it knwon whether $kM_n(k)$ has finite injective dimension as a module over itself (or even finite global dimension)?

Comment: I think I long ago computed the quiver got some small examples like 2x2 matrices over F_2 but I don't  quite remember

Comment: It has infinite global dimension

Comment: I know it is not self injective but not the injective dimension

Comment: Thanks, it would be interesting to see if the injective dimension is finite for n=2 (meaning it is a Gorenstein algebra). I'll try a bit for small fields.

Comment: What is situation for the general linear group?  Does it have infinite injective dimension?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The group algebra of the general linear group over a finite field? As a group algebra it is selfinjective over any field (which is equivalent to injective dimension 0).

Comment: Yes sorry I was not thinking.

Comment: @Mare, I have now correctly computed a bound quiver for $F_2M_2(F_2)$. I get 4 vertices, 2 of which are isolated.  The remaining vertices each have one arrow to the other and one of the vertices has a loop.  The relations say each path of length two is zero so it is a radical square zero algebra.  The simple for the looped vertex appears twice in the socle and so the algebra is not Frobenius.  Is this finite Gorenstein dimension?

Comment: @Mare, I guess the result of https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-01/S0002-9939-2011-10921-3/S0002-9939-2011-10921-3.pdf says this is not Gorenstein for the two element field

Comment: Yes, radical square zero is never Gorenstein unless it is selfinjective or of finite global dimension. Thanks.

Comment: The calculation is still relevant for the thread: In this case the algebra is representation finite and one can really classify all modules (probably one of the only cases).

Comment: @Mare, the module category for GL_n is a full subcategory.  I think this is the only case the group has finite representation type.

Comment: @Mare, it seems the group GL_2 is finite representation type but for n>2 GL_n is not.

Comment: @Mare, I made a mistake in my computation for $F_2M_2(F_2)$.  It is not radical square zero.  In fact it has infinite representation type and I believe it is a string algebra. There is one path of length 2 that is not 0

Answer (score 8):

As Ben Steinberg has been suggesting in the comments, the representation theory of these have been studied for quite awhile.  His book on this, *the Representation Theory of Finite Monoids*, is an excellent modern general reference for how to think about these.

The general theme is that the maximal subgroups in $M_n(k)$, namely the groups $GL_m(k)$ for $m=0, \dots, n$, control the representation theory.  For example there is a recollment diagram of the abelian categories:
$$ GL_n(k)\text{- modules}
\begin{array}{c} \stackrel{q}{\longleftarrow} \\[-.08in]
\stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} \\[-.08in] \stackrel{p}{\longleftarrow}
\end{array}
M_n(k)\text{- modules}
\begin{array}{c} \stackrel{l}{\longleftarrow} \\[-.06in] \stackrel{e}{\longrightarrow} \\[-.08in]
\stackrel{r}{\longleftarrow}
\end{array} M_{n-1}(k)\text{- modules.} $$
From this, one sees that the irreducible modules for $M_n(k)$ come in two flavors: $GL_n(k)$ irreducibles on which singular matrices act trivially, and $M_{n-1}(k)$ irreducible modules `induced' up to $M_n(k)$. Curiously, in the finite field case, at least, these two types are related be tensoring with the determinant representation (perhaps first noticed in a 1980's paper by John Harris and me).

In particular, if $k$ is a finite field of order $q$, the irreducible representations of $M_n(k)$ can be sensibly labelled by $q$--regular Young diagrams with at most $n$ nonzero columns.  If $k$ is infinite, one should be getting all Young diagrams.

Finally, the category of representations of $M_n(k)$ is very much related to the abelian category of functors from finite dimensional $k$--vector spaces to $k$--vector spaces (dubbed the category of `generic representations' of $k$ in some of my papers), and much interesting calculational work has been figured out in this setting.

Comment: I guess it took me 18 minutes to type my answer since I hadn’t seen yours when I started :)

Comment: I've recently been talking to Ross Street on this stuff and your work too. Hope all is well

Comment: I remember ( from a long time ago) that some work of Leonid Krop might be relevant